# Chance to fail at rob command. (discordpy)

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so im making a currency bot, and im stuck at the rob command.
Is that possible to add "chances" to the code? i mean that when someone executes the command then ex: 45% that the robbery will not succeed? If yes, then how?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: For random chances you can use the `random` module. Then you can get a random chance of `X` percent by doing: `import random`, `random.uniform(0,1) < X / 100`.

Comment: Some code examples would be great to help you out some more.

Comment: @iLuvLogix when i said im stuck with it, i meant that i didnt knew how should i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is a way to do randomness in python. It is to use the random module.
Here's the `rob` command example :

```py
@bot.command()
async def rob(ctx):
    if random.randint(0, 100) <= 45:
        await ctx.send("Robbery has failed.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Robbery was successful.")
```

Result :
[image: result]

Don't forget to add `import random` in your code before referencing it, preferably add it at the top of your code